# another pandas apply throwing AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'whatever'

Tags: pandas, apply

This code should work, no? I used this pattern a bunch of times before and not it's throwing an error. What am i missing?

```
table=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[3,4]})
table["c"]=table.apply(lambda x:x.a)
```

I'm getting

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'a'
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Forgot the `axis` argument: `table.apply(lambda x:x.a, axis=1)`.

Comment: yeah. thanks!!!